# Enviar JSON para o PHP8 via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Preciso de uma grande ajuda.
Preciso enviar um JSON para o PHP via AJAX/JQuery porém algo não está dando certo.
Possuo um arquivo JS com o comando:

```js
$('#save').click(function(e) {
    submit();
});


function submit() {
    let json = $('#textarea').text();
    let value = {values: json}
    $.ajax({
    method: "post",
    url: "server.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(value),
    beforeSend:  e => console.log(),
    success: e => console.log(e)
    });
};
```

E outro PHP que recebe o que o AJAX envia

```php
if (file_get_contents("php://input")) {
    $dados = file_get_contents("php://input", true);
    $obj = json_decode($dados);
    print_r($obj->values);
gravar($obj);
};

gravar($data);
  function gravar($obj){
    global $conection;
      foreach ($obj->pessoas as $key => $value) {
        $insert_pessoa = "insert into pessoas(nome)values(:nome_pessoa)";
        $insert = $conection->prepare($insert_pessoa);
        $insert->bindParam(':nome_pessoa', $value->nome);
        $insert->execute();
      };
  };
```

Os dados contidos no JSON serão utilizados pra gravar no DB e é aí que mora o problema.
Eu tenho um textarea com uma string que será mandada via AJAX para o PHP que por sua vez irá processá-la e depois gravá-la no DB.
Reparem que no final do código AJAX temos um retorno do PHP. Eu recebo esse retorno perfeitamente bem porém, as informações contidas no JSON não são gravadas no DB.

Imagine o seguinte:
Considere que a string do textarea seja

```php
'{"pessoas":[{"nome":"José","filhos":["a","b","c"]},{"nome":"Maria","filhos":["d","e","f"]}]}'
```

Se eu fizer desta forma aí funciona:

```php
if (file_get_contents("php://input")) {
    $dados = file_get_contents("php://input", true);
    $obj = json_decode($dados);
    print_r($obj->values);
    //gravar($obj);
  };

$myjson = '{"pessoas":[{"nome":"José","filhos":["a","b","c"]},{"nome":"Maria","filhos":["d","e","f"]}]}';
$data = json_decode($myjson);
gravar($data);
function gravar($obj){
    global $conection;
    foreach ($obj->pessoas as $key => $value) {
      $insert_pessoa = "insert into pessoas(nome)values(:nome_pessoa)";
      $insert = $conection->prepare($insert_pessoa);
      $insert->bindParam(':nome_pessoa', $value->nome);
      $insert->execute();
      };
  };
```

Alguém poderia por gentileza ajudar??

Comment: você verificou se não está ocorrendo um erro na query  ? o execute retorna um valor booleano , tente validar  veja se ocorreu um erro com $insert->errorInfo();